# Is Passbolt secure against root access?

Tags: password-management

Is the Passbolt password manager secure against root access, e.g. if I install Passbolt onto a VPS can it be considered secure or could the VPS host access the passwords stored within it?

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I'm one of passbolt developer.

If an attacker has root access to the server they can inject additional javascript to try to perform different type of attack. To our knowledge it is not possible to craft a JavaScript that would allow an attacker to get access to the private key of the end user and/or the passphrase. If you manage to craft this, do get in touch with us at security@passbolt.com.

That being said, it is possible for the attacker to breach the following:
- Confidentiality: the attacker can create/edit a user to trick another user into sharing the password with attacker. This could mitigated in the future using key signatures (for example the admin signing all the users keys).
- Availability: root access means obviously that all passwords can be deleted / tampered with.
- Integrity: idem.

Comment: If an attacker has root access, they can do a hell of a lot more than just inject javascript.

Comment: Passbolt is a web based password manager, encryption/decryption is done in the browser extension. (cf. your previous comment mention capturing keystroke on the server, which is not relevant in this case).

Comment: Oh is it a separate extension, not just client-side encryption?

Comment: Yes http://github.com/passbolt/passbolt_browser_extension

Comment: OK then, my bad!

Comment: Thanks for this. As you don't mention it can I also assume that no private keys, etc are kept on the server that could be used to decrypt the passwords?

Comment: No private key is kept on the server. The private key is stored in the client using chrome.storage (with sync' disabled). https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Maybe they can't get the private key, but wouldn't it be trivial to just send any decrypted passwords on to some other server, if they have the ability to inject javascript? The correct answer to the OP's question is "no". Root access to the server is "game over" for security.

Comment: > "Wouldn't it be trivial to just send any decrypted passwords on to some other server, if they have the ability to inject javascript".

To our knowledge it's not trivial because the decrypted password is not stored in the DOM the page has access to, but inside the web extension which live in a different sandbox. However it is possible with root access to create a user and trick the victim to share a password with that user.